# Javascript alternatives to extending native objects

Tags: javascript

I have an HTMLCollection:
`document.getElementsByClassName('done')` and now i want to implement a function `addEventListeners`.Now i can do it like this:

```
Object.prototype.addEventListeners = function(argument){
        Object.values(this).forEach(function(element, index) {
        });
    };
```

But i have read in numerous websites that extending native objects is a bad idea.So what are the alternatives?

Comment: why don't use a framework like JQuery or AngularJS ?

Comment: @FarukT i'm doing this for a better understanding of JS

Comment: As an alternate, you can attach a delegate to parent, if they have same parent or you can loop over on elements. You can use `Array.from(elementList, (el)=> { el.addEventListener(evenName, handler)})`

Comment: @str i'm not asking why it's bad,i'm asking for alternatives

Comment: @Rajesh but how can i turn into a handler

Comment: @askoasksao Just create your own class or functions which you pass arguments to (e.g. a selector and events). But that is also briefly mentioned in the duplicate question.

Comment: Handler is something that will handle an event. I guess you mean a utility function like `addEventListener`. There are few ways for this: 1. Add it to prototype(*Like in your code*). 2. Bleed it to global scope(`window.addEventListeners = ...`). 3. Create a utility can add it to this. This way, irrespective to domain/project, you will have your function(*Like jQuery, $().on(...)*). Personally, I prefer 3rd option. Issue with first 2 approach is, they are available on global scope, so anyone can change it and break your site.

Comment: @Rajesh thanks,utility is what i was looking for

Comment: If you extend natives, you should use `HTMLCollection` in this case

Comment: @JonasW.—HTMLCollection is a host object, not a native object. ;-) Extending host objects is worse than extending native objects, since host objects are not as controlled.